# Spring cloud gateway guide fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am attempting to follow the guide here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/#scratch but it fails on the circuit breaker step.

Specifically when adding the code:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p
            .path("/get")
            .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
        .route(p -> p
            .host("*.circuitbreaker.com")
            .filters(f -> f.circuitBreaker(config -> config.setName("mycmd")))
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80")).
        build();
}
```

When I attempt to run the application now, if fails with:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method myRoutes in com.example.springcloudgatewaypoc.Application required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilterFactory' in your configuration.
```

I used the spring starter the guide gave and tried different versions of java (8 and 17).

The first of the guide, just adding the Hello World filter worked.

Here is my full working code:

```
package com.example.springcloudgatewaypoc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p
            .path("/get")
            .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
        .route(p -> p
            .host("*.circuitbreaker.com")
            .filters(f -> f.circuitBreaker(config -> config.setName("mycmd")))
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80")).
        build();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

And pom (1.8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-gateway-poc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j` to `spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j`.

Comment: this fix works!